# react ajax call is undefined at first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm using Axios to make an AJAX call and the data returns undefined and then it consoles the array after a few seconds. I've tried componentDidMount and componentWillMount. I've tried making a constructor with initial state as the props. getInitial state is deprecated unless using React.createClass.

Here's my code, anything helps!

actions/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_STRAINS } from './types';
const ROOT_URL = `https://www.cannabisreports.com/api/v1.0/strains?sort=name&page=3`;

export function fetchStrains() {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get(ROOT_URL)
             .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: FETCH_STRAINS,
                    payload: response.data.data
                })
             })
             .catch( error => console.log(error));
    }
}
```

reducer/index.js

```
import { FETCH_STRAINS } from '../actions/types';
import initialState from './initialState';
export default function(state = initialState.strains, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_STRAINS:
            return { ...state, strains: action.payload };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from './actions';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
       this.props.fetchStrains();   
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

         {this.props.strains === undefined ? console.log("this is undefined") : console.log(this.props.strains)}

      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps( state ) {
    return { strains: state.strains.strains }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing isn't because your code is wrong. From a quick glance it looks like you're doing it right.

The problem is that your app exists and is showing before you have all the data ready. The axios call takes a very long time to complete. Until it's done, your app is showing something to the user, whether you like it or not.

So between startup and data arrival, `strains` is going to be `undefined`. You'll have to decide what to show the user while they're waiting. A common solution is a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use async actions & need to import thunk-middleware while you combine your reducers.

```
export function fetchStrains() {

// Thunk middleware knows how to handle functions.
// It passes the dispatch method as an argument to the function,
// thus making it able to dispatch actions itself.

return function (dispatch) {

// First dispatch: the app state is updated to inform
// that the API call is starting.

// The function called by the thunk middleware can return a value,
// that is passed on as the return value of the dispatch method.

// In this case, we return a promise to wait for.
// This is not required by thunk middleware, but it is convenient for us.

 axios.get(ROOT_URL)
         .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_STRAINS,
                payload: response.data.data
            })
         })
         .catch( error => console.log(error));

 }
}
```